# Adding the date/time (DD/MM/YY HH:MM) information dynamically at the end of ZIP file

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, zip, csv

I want to add the current date/time (DD/MM/YY HH:MM) information dynamically at the end of ZIP file when backing daily via IBM cognos export. Then How can I export CSV formatted them using script?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ gives you tools you can use to extract the current date and time from a directory listing of the ZIP file and then rename the desired ZIP file.

However, the free 7-Zip.org makes standard ZIP files if desired, and has a command line version which will incorporate the date and time into the file name. Examples are at http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/b7f6ada4 and http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5b4ba017 .